# org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, jpql, dao

I have below code in my DAO:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CustomerData " +
             "WHERE custId = :custId AND deptId = :deptId";
Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("custId", custId);
query.setParameter("deptId", deptId);
long count = (long) query.uniqueResult(); // ERROR THROWN HERE
```

Hibernate throws  below exception at the marked line:

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result:

I am not sure whats happening as `count(*)` will always return only one row.

Also when i run this query on db directly, it return result as 1. So whats the issue?

Comment: the issue is that you ask for a uniqueResult, meaning there may only be one row returned, but the query finds more than 1 result.

Comment: but count(*) will always return only 1 row

Comment: I just told you what triggers a NonUniqueResultException. I agree that for a count it is weird, but still.
have you tried without the UniqueResult constraint?

Comment: What is CustomerData? Abstract class?

Comment: @user3198603 have you resolved the issue? Did you get the reason of problem?

Comment: What's the Hibernate version?

Comment: As @Grox13 answered here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40233705/8338411) Alternatively, If you are using `Optional<>` change it to `List<>`

Comment: If you have more then one row in your query result, you should use f.e.: NHibernate.IQuery.ListAsync instead of UniqueResultAsync

Comment: Dou you have another class extending CustomerData ? Is this class also mapped?

Answer (score 49):

It seems like your query returns more than one result check the database. In documentation of `query.uniqueResult()` you can read:

> Throws: org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException - if there is more
>   than one matching result

If you want to avoid this error and still use unique result request, you can use this kind of workaround `query.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();`

Answer (score 26):

Hibernate 
 Optional findTopByClientIdAndStatusOrderByCreateTimeDesc(Integer clientId, Integer status);

"findTop"!! The only one result!

Answer (score 25):

I don't think other answers explained the key part: why "COUNT(*)" returns more than one result?

I just encountered the same issue today, and what I found out is that if you have another class extending the target mapped class (here "CustomerData"), Hibernate will do this magic.

Hope this will save some time for other unfortunate guys.

Comment: This should be the accapted answer. And count always return 1, no excuse.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Hibernate is probably doing a UNION with both classes CustomerData  and its child.

Comment: This was the problem I experienced. My solution was to add the class annotation which defines polymorphism=explicit.

Answer (score 14):

Generally This exception is thrown from Oracle when query result (which is stored in an Object in your case), can not be cast to the desired object.
for example when result is a

```
List<T>
```

and you're putting the result into a single T object.

In case of casting to long error, besides it is recommended to use wrapper classes so that all of your columns act the same, I guess a problem in transaction or query itself would cause this issue.

Comment: it is the answer!

Answer (score 7):

It means that the query you wrote returns more than one element(result) while your code expects a single result.

Answer (score 1):

Could this exception be thrown during an unfinished transaction, where your application is attempting to create an entity with a duplicate field to the identifier you are using to try find a single entity?

In this case the new (duplicate) entity will not be visible in the database as the transaction won't have, and will never be committed to the db. The exception will still be thrown however.

Answer (score 1):

Received this error while doing otherwise correct hibernate queries. The issue was that when having a class extend another hibernate was counting both. This error can be "fixed" by adding a method to your repository class.

By overriding the class count you can manually determine the way this is counted.

```
@Override 
public Integer count(Page<MyObject> page) {
   // manual counting method here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using JPQL and wanted to return `Map`. In my case, the reason was that I wanted to get `Map<String, String>`, but had to expect `List<Map<String, String>>` :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your table, where one entity occurring multiple time's.

I had the same error, with this data :

| id | amount | clientid | createdate | expiredate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 428 | 100 | 427 | 19/11/2021 | 19/12/2021 |
| 464 | 100 | 459 | 22/11/2021 | 22/12/2021 |
| 464 | 100 | 459 | 22/11/2021 | 22/12/2021 |

You see here `clientid` occurring two times with 464.

I solved it by deleting one row :

| id | amount | clientid | createdate | expiredate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 428 | 100 | 427 | 19/11/2021 | 19/12/2021 |
| 464 | 100 | 459 | 22/11/2021 | 22/12/2021 |

Answer (score 1):

I have found the core of the problem:

**result of SELECT COUNT(*) can be a list, if there is a GROUP BY in the query,**

and sometimes Hibernate rewrite your HQL and put a GROUP BY into it, just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your query returns more than one result set.
 In API Docs uniqueResult() method says that 
  **Convenience method to return a single instance that matches
 the query, or null if the query returns no results**

**uniqueResult()** method yield only single resultset

Answer (score 0):

Thought this might help to someone, it happens because "When the number of data queries is greater than 1".[reference](http://www.programmersought.com/article/1864419699/)

Answer (score 0):

As what Ian Wang said, I suspect you are using a repository from spring. And a few days ago you just copy past a class and forgot to delete it when it is finally unused. Check that repository, and see if there is multiple same class of table you use. The count is not the count of rows, but the count of the table problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error is caused by
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`
in application.properties file replacing it with
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` solved the issue, but it still depends on your needs to decide which configuration you need in your project, for more insights on the topic check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring#:%7E:text=%22spring.-,jpa.,database%20table%20instance%20is%20droped.).

Answer (score -1):

This means that orm technology is not preprogrammed to give you which results you are looking for because there are too many of the same results in the database. for example If there is more than one same value in my database and I want to get it back, you will encounter the error you get with the select query.

Comment: Your post is unreadable but seems to be an attempt to answer the question. I recommend to [edit] with some help from a more fluent person to improve this according to [answer].

Answer (score -7):

First you must test the query list size; here a example:

```
long count;
if (query.list().size() > 0)
    count=(long) criteria.list().get(0);   
else
    count=0;            
return count;
```